# tinymce doesn't return the text written

Tags: php, tinymce

Today I faced a problem with TinyMCE.

I just want to make a simple blogging system, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['tinymce'])) {$content = $_POST['tinymce']; echo $content;}
    if(isset($_POST['save'])) {$content = $_POST['save']; echo $content;}

?>
    <div class="container" id="content">
        <pre><?php print_r($_POST); ?></pre>
        <form method="post" action="post.php">
            <textarea id="tinymce"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="save" style="color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);background:none;border:none;" value="action">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Here's the code I'm using.
I also added **print_r()**, and here's the result when I click ACTION button:
[image]
Any help?

Comment: There must be another issue here. TinyMCE does make a new editor region, but when you type it updates the text in the hidden <textarea> element os that you can still reference it. i can see that your textarea doesn't have a `name=` property. Can you try to add `name="tinymce"` and then save, and see if the index is available in the `print_r` at that point?

Comment: `<textarea name="tinyme" id="tinymce"></textarea>`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Dagon and @Ohgodwhy, I needed to place **name=** tag for it to work. Thanks again!
[image]